# Is it possible to map lead case to a opportunity case?

Tags: opportunity, leads, lead-conversion, field-mapping

I create a lookup relationship between Lead(Parent) and Case(Child) Object .When I convert the lead,the lead case field will be updated into opportunity case field.
Can anyone explain how to do this if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom mapping.
"
Custom lookup fields can be mapped to a lookup field pointing to the same object. For example, a lead custom lookup field pointing to the Account object can be mapped to a contact custom lookup field that also points to the Account object.
"

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_mapleads_guidelines.htm&type=5

Comment: No corresponding(related) fields were mapped when using the custom field map **.I have create lookup relationship between lead(parent)& case(child) and opportunity(parent)& case(child).when the lead is converted, change the mapping of the cases to the opportunity created because of conversion.** Help me find a way to do this.@MenashYA